# Perform in-memory update of SQLite3 database file using Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a Django application using a database with approximately 1.8 million rows in the primary table. This table is read-only in the application.

Once per day I need to perform update_or_create on the entire database to refresh the data with an updated file from an external source. I imagine the fastest way to do this would be to load the table into a RAM-based table, perform all the updates, and then flush it back to the SQLite3 file. Alternately, I could create a new table, bulk-load everything, and then swap the new table into place of the original table. Either approach works conceptually.

What I am wondering is how do I go about doing either of these? Which is preferred from a performance perspective? Which will have the least disk IO?

Any suggestions or links on either approach are appreciated.

Comment: SQLite has pretty darn fast writes as long as you don't churn the data (i.e. lots of interleaved deletes and inserts, which causes exponential slowdown due to B-tree fragmentation). So the new-table-then-swap approach should be very fast, with none of the complexity of the RAM-table approach. Neither one will have overmuch disk I/O if you chunk things into large transactions.

Comment: Thanks... I'll try that approach. FWIW, Django's update_or_create() method is churning somewhere; even inside a transaction this is taking 25-30 minutes to complete for 1.8M rows.

Comment: Hmm. I've seen SQLite do ~100k inserts/s (on a relatively simple table with a couple indexes). I think you need to find a way to look at the generated queries (I'm afraid I don't know Django).

Comment: update_or_create() first has to look up the row by some criteria: if it exists, it updates the remaining columns; if it doesn't exist, then it creates it. So there are a lot of queries going on for each row.

Comment: Ah, I see. Still, seems a little on the slow side (SQLite tends to have faster reads than writes, for example). Are you sure the search query is using the right index(es) to look up the data? If you run `explain query plan <sql>` in the sqlite3 console with the queries you'll get a nice summary of what the DB is doing for each one.

Comment: Cool, thanks... I'll investigate further.